# How can I put together a broken word?

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, if-statement, char

I'm building a guess the word game that breaks the random word the program chooses into individual letters. The player guesses by the letter instead of the whole word. Now I need to find a way to put those letters together so they make the whole word so the program can check it and break the loop

```
  string[] secretWord = new string[5];
        secretWord[0] = "Pong";
        secretWord[1] = "Crash";
        secretWord[2] = "Joust";
        secretWord[3] = "1942";
        secretWord[4] = "Tron";
        int guessedRight = 0;
        string name = "";
        string guess = "";
        char letter = 'A';
        
       
        Random random = new Random();
        int answer = random.Next(secretWord.Length);
        char[] brokenword = secretWord[answer].ToCharArray();

        //Game Starts
        Console.WriteLine("Enter your name");
        name = Console.ReadLine();

        //Game Loop
        while (guess != secretWord[answer])
        {               
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Your Letter, {0}", name);
            
            foreach (char c in brokenword)
            {
                

                if (c == letter)
                {
                    Console.Write(letter);
                    
                }
                Console.Write("- ");

                                   

            }
            letter = Convert.ToChar(Console.Read());
           
        }
        Console.WriteLine("You Win!");          
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: What does "put together" mean? So let's say the word is `"Tron"` and I enter the letters `r`, `q`, `v`, `n`, `o`, and `t`. I've entered all the letters of `"Tron"`, but also some extras. Is it sufficient that I entered all the letters? Or must I enter all of the letters in a continuous sequence? And what if the word is "mane" or "mean" - does the order of my guesses matter?

Comment: So the program picks one random word from the array for ex. Tron. The player is trying to guess the word but is only allowed single character inputs (think hangman).  So far the program does not recognize the player's individual inputs as the full word so the loop cannot be broken, I need it to recognize that when the player guesses T, r, o, n  that it is Tron. Order of the letters entered does not matter.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing some logic in your code, you don't ever update `guess` You could do something like this:

```
string[] secretWord = new string[5];
secretWord[0] = "Pong";
secretWord[1] = "Crash";
secretWord[2] = "Joust";
secretWord[3] = "1942";
secretWord[4] = "Tron";
int guessedRight = 0;
string name = "";
string guessString = string.Empty;
char[] guessArray = null;
char letter = 'A';
        
       
Random random = new Random();
int answer = random.Next(secretWord.Length);
char[] brokenword = secretWord[answer].ToCharArray();
guessString = new string('_', brokenword.Length);
guessArray = guessString.ToCharArray();

//Game Starts
Console.WriteLine("Enter your name");
name = Console.ReadLine();

//Game Loop
while (guessString != secretWord[answer])
{               
    Console.WriteLine("Enter Your Letter, {0}", name);
    letter = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadKey().KeyChar);
    Console.WriteLine();
            
    for (int i = 0; i < brokenword.Length; i++)
    {
        char c = brokenword[i]

        if (c == letter)
        {
            Console.Write(letter);
            guessArray[i] = c;
            guessString = new string(guessArray)
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine(guessString);
}

Console.WriteLine("You Win!");          

Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take on what you're doing:

```
Random random = new Random();

string[] secretWords = new string[] { "Pong", "Crash", "Joust", "1942", "Tron" };
string secretWord = secretWords[random.Next(secretWords.Length)];

Console.WriteLine("Enter your name");
string name = Console.ReadLine() ?? "Player";
Console.Clear();
Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);

string guessedWord = "";
List<char> guessedLetters = new List<char>();

while (true)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Enter Your Letter, {name}");
    guessedLetters.Add(char.ToLowerInvariant(Console.ReadKey().KeyChar));
    Console.Clear();
    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);

    guessedWord = String.Concat(secretWord.Select(c => guessedLetters.Contains(char.ToLowerInvariant(c)) ? c : '_'));
    if (guessedWord != secretWord)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Your current guess {guessedWord} from {String.Join(", ", guessedLetters)}");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"You Win! The word was {guessedWord}");
        break;
    }
}

Console.ReadKey();
```

The key here is how the `guessedWord` is created with this line:

```
guessedWord = String.Concat(secretWord.Select(c => guessedLetters.Contains(char.ToLowerInvariant(c)) ? c : '_'));
```

This line checks each letter in the `secretWord` and includes it in the `guessedWord` if and only if the letter is in the `guessedLetters` list. It uses `char.ToLowerInvariant` to allow a lowercase or uppercase letter to match.

Answer (score -1):

create a list:

```
var wordBuilt = new List<string>()
```

inside your if statement you can simply add the letter inside the list that you created.
At the end you just need to call the .Join() method from the list and write the results in console.

Comment: please show where this code is placed, where to call `.Add`, and where to add `.Join`.